# Javascript: add CSS property to a div when it doesn't have a certain other div inside

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I would like to add a margin-bottom to a div when the image div inside is not there, with Javascript. I can't add a class noimage because it will not work with the CMS I need to use (Typo3), and i'm pretty sure I'm going to have to do this with JS.

It's in quite a complexe structure but it looks something like this:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="content"></div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="content"></div>
    <div class="image"></div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="content"></div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="content"></div>
    <div class="image"></div>
</div>
```

So when there is no image, the wrapper div needs to have a margin-bottom.

Thank you very much for your help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
$('.wrapper').not(':has(.image)').css('margin-bottom', '10px')
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/aMdtg/)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
$(".wrapper").each(function() {
    if($(this).find(".image").length == 0) {
        $(this).css('margin-bottom', '10px');
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

a shortcut would be :

```
$('.wrapper:not(:has(.image))').css('margin-bottom', '10px');
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest adding a class and adding your `margin-bottom` and whatever else to that, you can select them with [`:not`](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) and [`:has`](http://api.jquery.com/has-selector/)

```
$(".wrapper:not(:has(.image))").addClass("no-image");
```

However if you're set on using an inline style and don't want to use a class, use the `.css()` function:

```
$(".wrapper:not(:has(.image))").css("margin-bottom","15px");
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally the solution is got with Jquery.Try this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MohammadHamza/ZkwhL/).
This is the thing you want.
This is the Jquery

```
$('.wrapper').has('.image').css('margin-bottom','30px');
```

Comment: "So when there is *no* image, the wrapper div needs to have a margin-bottom."